# Bound of infinity norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I am reading the paper about matrix completion, and encounter the following problem.

Assume $U\in R^{n_1 \times r}$ and $V\in R^{n_2 \times r}$ have orthogonal columns, and define the operation $P_T(X)$ as
\begin{align}
P_T(X) = P_UX +XP_V- P_UXP_V
\end{align}
where $P_U = UU^T$ and $P_V = VV^T$.
In addition, we define
\begin{align}
\mu=\max \left\{  \frac{n_1}{r} \max_i \left\| P_U e_i \right\|_{2}^2, \frac{n_2}{r} \max_i\left\| P_V e_i \right\|_2^2 \right\}
\end{align}
Assume $Z = P_T(Z)$, then I want to prove the following holds, $\forall a,b$
\begin{align}
\left\| n_1n_2 Z_{a,b} P_T\left(e_a e_b^T\right) -Z\right\|_{\infty} \leqslant \mu r(n_1 +n_2)\|Z\|_{\infty},
\end{align}
where $e_a$ and $e_b$ denote the stadard basis,  $Z_{a,b}$ denotes the $(a,b)$th entry of $Z$, and the $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$ means the maximum absolute value of the entries in a matrix, i.e., $\|X \|_{\infty} = \max_{i,j}|X_{i,j}|$.
Is there any clue to prove this?

Comment: what is $Z_{a,b}$?

Comment: $Z_{a,b}$ denotes the $(a,b)$th entry of $Z$, and I have updated the question.

Comment: How can orthogonal matrices be non-square? Do you mean each of $U$ and $V$ has orthonormal columns?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.